# How pass parameter "this" on change event using Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrow-functions

I usually have the code something like this:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<select id="mySelectOne">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$("#mySelectOne").on("change",function(){
    var value = $(this).val(); // Return the value selected
    alert(value); 
});
```

*Using Arrow Function:*

```
$("#mySelectTwo").on("change", () => {
    var value = $(this).val(); //"this" is undefined
    alert(value);
});
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/kr1hxxtm/

When I use arrow function the value of `this` is `undefined` (*Should refer to select element*).

**How can I pass the parameter?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. That's half the point of arrow functions, they close over `this` instead of having their own that's set by how they're called. For the use case in the question, if you want `this` set by jQuery when calling the handler, the handler would need to be a `function` function.

But if you have a reason for using an arrow (perhaps you want to use `this` for what it means outside the arrow), you can use `e.currentTarget` instead of `this` if you like:

```
$("#mySelectTwo").on("change", e => {      // Note `e` argument
    var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();  // ...and using it here
    alert(value);
});
```

The `currentTarget` on the event object is the same as what jQuery sets `this` to when calling your handler.

Comment: It's a good answer!

Comment: @CMedina: Glad that helped! If you'll un-accept it, though, I've posted it to the earlier question that Rory linked, so I'll just delete it here.